# AngularJs calendar decreases in width in IE

Tags: css, angularjs

So this is about AngularJs and the uib datepicker.

This bug doesn't appear in Chrome and Firefox. But only in IE (tested in IE11).

The calendar is in a `div` that has `width: 100%;`.

When I go to the view with the calendar, it covers 100% of the div.
But as soon as I click on a date, it becomes half in width.
I tried to add the !important directive, but didn't make any difference.

Unfortunately I cannot access developer tools (security reasons at the office) so I cannot see what is happening. But it looks like the `div` and its width shrinks to the half.

Anybody recognizes this bug?

Comment: It is very hard to debug without seeing an example. Developer tools is a essential tool for web developer, ask it to be unlocked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was caused by the css directive `table-layout: fixed;`
Changed it to `table-layout: auto;` solved the problem.